# HTC Pico Windows10

Tags: android, bootloader

Im trying to unlock bootloader in HTC Pico I get error code 10 in Windows 10 when I connect my phone through USB cable in Fastboot mode(Enabled USB Debugging). But I can use HTC Sync normally with all functions. My drivers are upto date.Im using Android studio with SDK and fastboot downloaded from HTC Website.My USB 2.0 is perfectly working fine when I connect pen drive or my phone by normal restarting.Any suggestions on how to unlock bootloader in my HTC Pico phone?

Comment: Last time I unlocked a HTC phone, it didn't work on windows 10, only windows 7. Got an older computer you could try it on?

Comment: I've got an old windows 7 computer.It has 1 GB RAM.Not sure what softwares I should use.Cant install Android Studio because it needs 2 GB RAM.

Comment: iirc you can just use adb in command line.  These instructions look similar to what I did http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2317870

Comment: Sorry,I have 1GB RAM computer still cant install android sdk(AndroidStudio) in my old computer.Any other older versions???